# PHP - query not quite right

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select time from this column.

[image: Picture 1]

Column type is datetime.

I have this code now and it's work but not as I want:

```
$qcreatetime = mysql_query("SELECT create_time FROM ".SQL_HP_DB.".account WHERE id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");

while ($rowcreatetime = mysql_fetch_array($qcreatetime))

{$createtime = $rowcreatetime["create_time"];

echo $createtime;}
```

I got this result with printed echo:

SELECT create_time FROM account_3.account WHERE id='2'

I'm still getting this error:

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm asking for solving this problem with old mysql because of I'm using old website where is used old mysql.

Comment: `echo "SELECT create_time FROM ".SQL_HP_DB.".account WHERE id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";` and check what query printed. update here

Comment: I got this result with echo: SELECT create_time FROM account_3.account WHERE id='2'

Answer (score 0):

This is the right syntax:

```
"SELECT create_time FROM ".SQL_HP_DB.".account WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

You had a single and double quote before and after the session variable. Those were wrong.

Comment: I already have this right syntax, but I'm still getting error which is mentioned above. @Tony T.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in another query so now everything working as I wanted.